# Event Listener in Reactjs for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

currently I'm building an application in Reactjs and working on a task.
The task includes select/highlight text from the page and display that selected/highlighted text in the input field (as shown in the photo)
[image]

Here I have implemented logic for this by using **onMouseUpCapture** (also I have tried **onMouseUp**) event from react and got the selected/highlighted text from **window.getSelection().toString()** and it was working as expected when I view this page on browser from laptop/computer.

But when I open the same application from a mobile browser I was not getting the selected/highlighted text to the input field.

[image]

Can anyone help me to know, are there any other event listeners that we need for mobile browsers or how to make it to work in mobile browsers. I did some google but couldn't find a solution for this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the touch events when using mobile browsers, I believe that the counterpart for `onMouseUp` event in mobile is the `onTouchEnd`event.

You can read more about it in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchend